# Unable to setup chaperone Development Environment(DE)

Tags: ubuntu, ansible, vmware-tools

I was going through the steps to setup chaperone as mentioned here [Chaperone Setup](https://github.com/vmware/chaperone/blob/master/docs/setup.md)

Using Ubuntu 14.04 for setting up development environment.

However, I am stuck at step "Setup the DE with basic tools". 
When i execute command

`cd ansible/playbooks/ansible
ansible-playbook --ask-sudo-pass -i inventory ansible.yml`

It fails with error: - "Failed to update apt cache"

I am clueless at preset how to avoid this error. It will be great if someone guides me how can i get more details about error, trackbacks etc.

Error:`Task [ansible: update apt cache] *******************************
fatal:[localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "Failed to update apt cache."}`

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure you can convince Ansible to give your more verbose error message in this case. You should try to execute `apt-get update` manually to see if there is any error.

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov, 'apt-get update' was throwing an error '404 page Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]. So i have fixed that by updating the file /etc/apt/sources.list on my ubuntu machine. Now the ansible command works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Answer from the comments:

> I'm not sure you can convince Ansible to give your more verbose error message in this case. You should try to execute `apt-get update` manually to see if there is any error.